# Nginx redirecionamento sem proxy

Tags: html, arquivo, nginx

Estou configurando o Nginx para receber requisições e delegar a um servidor NodeJs. Porém existe uma url/rota que precisa renderizar um html estático fora do servidor NodeJs. Caso semelhante a esse:

```
upstream node-upstream {
   least_conn;
   server localhost:3000;
   keepalive 64;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 0.0.0.0;
   charset utf-8;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://node-upstream;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 0.0.0.0;

   charset utf-8;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/adm.access.log  main;

   location /adm {
      alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/adm;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de isso ser feito ? Com as regras acima não funciona, o Servidor NodeJs responde primeiro.

Comment: Tentou colocar ambos locations dentro do mesmo server? Já que ambos servers são os mesmos, parece que vc só esta repetindo as coisas, basta que ambos locations fiquem no primeiro, creio que o o location /adm vá primeiro, mas faz tempo que não uso ngnix então não posso afirmar

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado! Sou iniciante nessa parte de Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você criou dois `serve {}` com os mesmos parametros de `port` e `server_name`, logo provavelmente apenas o primeiro é reconhecido, o segundo é ignorado, para resolver basta colocar ambos `location{}` dentro do mesmo `serve {}`, assim:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 0.0.0.0;
   charset utf-8;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/adm.access.log  main;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://node-upstream;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /adm {
       alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/adm;
       index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```